# Invalid Argument Error while installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, windows

I got this error when I was installing ubuntu directly from CD choosing the option 'inside windows' [XP] , I had tested several times on C drive [30 GB free space] as well as on other drives with minimum 20 GB free space. how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you used wubi app to that this program very good but still have problem with somebody i'm one of them

try another partition

see that first may help you https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

then do that

1.with any program partition tools liked parted magic or acrions or other make unallocated free space partition take al least 5 giga free space

2.create any partition in that new unallocated space and make it fat32 not ntfs because ntfs make problem sometimes

3.make this new partition primary

4.format it with slow format from partiton program or if you hard drive old you can do that with this command in cmd format X:

x refer to new hard drive

5.after that make defragmentation for it

6.now try to install it

if problem continue change step number 2 and make it ntfs if still change step number 3 and make it logical

i know that wubi must be found to don't do any of above any install ubuntu like any software in windows but as i said it still have problem with it

so it's many solution that other advise us to do and you can search in google about wubi problem to see that

and the best is install ubuntu with default way as any operting system or install it in virtualbox and i see the second idea is best beacuse you will can use windows and linux in same time

Comment: Thanx for the precious Answer..